# Merge DFs on more than 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Consider the following data frames:

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
'type_a': ['nan', 'type3', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type5', 'type4'],
'q_a': [0, 0.9, 5.1, 3.0, 1.6, 1.1, 0.7],
'p_a': [0, 0.53, 0.71, 0.6, 0.53, 0.3, 0.33]
})
```

Edit: This is an extract of `base_df`. The original df 100 columns with around 500 observations.

```
table_df = pd.DataFrame({
'type': ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type3', 'type3', 'type3', 'type4', 'type4', 'type4', 'type4', 'type5', 'type5', 'type5', 'type6', 'type6'],
'q_value': [5.1, 3.1, 1.6, 1.3, 0.9, 0.85, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 0.4, 0.4],
'p_value': [0.71, 0.62, 0.71, 0.54, 0.53, 0.44, 0.5, 0.54, 0.33, 0.33, 0.32, 0.31, 0.28, 0.31, 0.16],
'sigma':[2.88, 2.72, 2.73, 2.79, 2.91, 2.41, 2.63, 2.44, 2.7, 2.69, 2.59, 2.67, 2.4, 2.67, 2.35]
})
```

Edit: The original `table_df` looks exactly like this one.

For every observation in `base_df`, I'd like to look up if the type matches with an entry in `table_df`, if yes:

- I'd like to look if there is an entry in `table_df` with the corresponding value `q_a` == `q_value`, if yes:

  - And there's only one value `q_value`, assign `sigma` to `base_df`.
  - If there are more than one values of `q_value`, compare `p_a` and assing the correct sigma to `base_df`.
- If there's no exactly matching value for `q_a` or `p_a` just use the next bigger value, in case there is no bigger value use the lower one and assign the corresponding value for `sigma` to column `sigma_a` in `base_df`.

**The resulting DF should look like this:**

```
id type_a q_a p_a   sigma_a 
1  nan    0   0     0       
2  type3  0.9 0.53  2.91    
3  type1  5.1 0.71  2.88    
4  type2  3   0.6   2.72    
5  type3  1.6 0.53  2.41    
6  type5  1.1 0.3   2.67    
7  type4  0.7 0.33  2.7
```

So far I use the code below:

```
mapping = (pd.merge_asof(base_df.sort_values('q_a'), 
                    table_df.sort_values('q_value'), 
                    left_on='q_a', 
                    left_by='type_a', 
                    right_on='q_value', 
                    right_by='type').set_index('id'))

base_df= (pd.merge_asof(base_df.sort_values('q_a'), 
                    table_df.sort_values('q_value'), 
                    left_on='q_a', 
                    left_by='type_a', 
                    right_on='q_value', 
                    right_by='type',
                    direction = 'forward')
                    .set_index('id')
                    .combine_first(mapping)
                    .sort_index()
                    .reset_index()
                    )
```

This "two step check routine" works, but I'd like to add the third step checking p_value.
How can I realize it?

Comment: Please provide more context and a clear example for others to understand better

Comment: Thanks, I did. Hope its more obvious now.

Comment: I still does not understand, as there is no `sigma_a` and `sigma_b` values in the initial data frames…

Comment: Yeah I dont think the question is clear to anyone. I recommend asking specific qns in particular where you tried some code, and also print the code

Comment: Sorry maye the example was too confusing. I simplified it.

Comment: I edited again and I think the example is clear now, Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and what's the error?

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think *Metrics* should not be separated into *A-segment* *B-segment*,
It supposed to concatenated into the same column and create a Metric like `Segment`.

---

Anyway, according to your description,
`table_df` is a reference table and they have the same criteria for `_a` and `_b`,
therefore I order them in hierarchical structure by following manipulation:

```
table_df.sort_values(by=["type","q_value","p_value"]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

```
    type    q_value p_value sigma
0   type1   5.10    0.71    2.88
1   type2   3.10    0.62    2.72
2   type3   0.85    0.44    2.41
3   type3   0.90    0.53    2.91
4   type3   1.30    0.54    2.79
5   type3   1.60    0.71    2.73
6   type4   0.50    0.33    2.69
7   type4   0.70    0.33    2.70
8   type4   0.70    0.50    2.63
9   type4   0.70    0.54    2.44
10  type5   1.10    0.28    2.40
11  type5   1.10    0.31    2.67
12  type5   1.20    0.32    2.59
13  type6   0.40    0.16    2.35
14  type6   0.40    0.31    2.67
```

[table_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGw5T.png)

`type`: a fully restrict condition
`q-value`&`p-value`: If there's no exactly matching value for `q_a` or `p_a` just use the next bigger value and assign the corresponding value for sigma to column `sigma_a` in `base_df`. If no bigger on, use the previous value in the reference table.

---

define the function for `_a` and `_b` (yeah they are the same)

`find_sigma_a` and `find_sigma_b`

```
def find_sigma_a(row):
    sigma_value = table_df[
            (table_df["type"]==row["type_a"]) & 
            (table_df["q_value"]>= row["q_a"]) & 
            (table_df["p_value"]>= row["p_a"])
        ]
    if row["type_a"] == 'nan':
        sigma_value = 0
    elif len(sigma_value) == 0:
        sigma_value = table_df[table_df["type"]==row["type_a"]].iloc[-1,3]
        # .iloc[-1,3] alternatively term ["sigma"].tail(1).values[0]
    else:
        sigma_value = sigma_value.iloc[0,3]
        # .iloc[0,3] alternatively term ["sigma"].head(1).values[0]
    return sigma_value
```

```
def find_sigma_b(row):
    sigma_value = table_df[
            (table_df["type"] == row["type_b"]) & 
            (table_df["q_value"] >= row["q_b"]) & 
            (table_df["p_value"] >= row["p_b"])
        ]
    if row["type_b"] == 'nan':
        sigma_value = 0
    elif len(sigma_value) == 0:
        sigma_value = table_df[table_df["type"]==row["type_b"]].iloc[-1,3]
        # .iloc[-1,3] alternatively term ["sigma"].tail(1).values[0]   
 else:
        sigma_value = sigma_value.iloc[0,3]
        # .iloc[0,3] alternatively term ["sigma"].head(1).values[0]
    return sigma_value
```

and then use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to apply these two functions

```
base_df["sigma_a"] = base_df.apply(find_sigma_a, axis = 1)
```

```
base_df["sigma_b"] = base_df.apply(find_sigma_b, axis = 1)
```

```
        type_a  q_a p_a     type_b  q_b p_b     sigma_a sigma_b
0       nan     0.0 0.00    type6   0.4 0.11    0.00    2.35
1       type3   0.9 0.53    type3   1.4 0.60    2.91    2.73
2       type1   5.1 0.71    type3   0.9 0.53    2.88    2.91
3       type2   3.0 0.60    type6   0.5 0.40    2.72    2.67
4       type3   1.6 0.53    type6   0.4 0.11    2.73    2.35
5       type5   1.1 0.30    type1   4.9 0.70    2.67    2.88
6       type4   0.7 0.33    type4   0.7 0.20    2.70    2.70
```

[image: result_2]

arrange the columns:

```
base_df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,6,3,4,5,7]]
```

```
    type_a  q_a p_a     sigma_a type_b  q_b p_b     sigma_b
0   nan     0.0 0.00    0.00    type6   0.4 0.11    2.35
1   type3   0.9 0.53    2.91    type3   1.4 0.60    2.73
2   type1   5.1 0.71    2.88    type3   0.9 0.53    2.91
3   type2   3.0 0.60    2.72    type6   0.5 0.40    2.67
4   type3   1.6 0.53    2.73    type6   0.4 0.11    2.35
5   type5   1.1 0.30    2.67    type1   4.9 0.70    2.88
6   type4   0.7 0.33    2.70    type4   0.7 0.20    2.70
```

[image: result_arr]
[Notebook_file](https://github.com/9joy1/public/blob/main/Aukru.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks!! You're right, I didn't mention the case if q_a is higher than q_value. If there's no exactly matching value for q_a or p_a just use the next bigger value, in case there is no bigger value, use the lower one and assign the corresponding value for sigma to column sigma_a in base_df. How do i change your code?

Comment: like the case {type6,q=0.5,p=0.4} use the lower one type6 reference table have two option in `p_value`: 0.16 and 0.31 which one you need ?

Comment: {type6, q = 0.5, p = 0.4} --> there's no matching value for q = 0.5, --> use next bigger one --> there is no bigger one, so use the next lower one --> choose q = 0.4 --> there's no matching value for p = 0.4 --> use next bigger one --> there is no bigger one, so use the next lower one --> choose p = 0.31 --> pick sigma = 2.67

Comment: I just modified them due to the description you gave.

Comment: I got "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" due .iloc[-1,3]. base_df has actually more columns than the example above.

Comment: Did you reorder the reference table `table_df.sort_values(by=["type","q_value","p_value"]).reset_index(drop = True)`

Comment: Yes, i reordered table_df

Comment: please check the URL from the bottom of the post, I upload the notebook file

Comment: Your notebook file works, also if i use the code in sypder it works. But it doesn't work anymore if base_df has more columns. I guess due to indexing with iloc instead of using the column labels.

Comment: .iloc[-1,3] trying to fetch last rows(the row location value is -1), and the sigma value(the column location value is 3)

Comment: Any idea whats the issue?

Comment: you mean, you have _a, _b, _c, _d,...etc. Then it should be a function find_sigma_x that can applied to x-segment

Comment: yes, i do have _a, _b, _c, _d and some other columns. if i add some random columns to base_df from my initial post, you're code still works. but it's not working with my original df.

Comment: can you show the head(10) and all the columns from your real base_df table_df

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I got it, instead of 'nan' I used np.nan :/